# Is there a way to get input() in python to auto enter?

Tags: python-3.x, user-input, barcode-scanner

I am writing a script that uses a barcode scanner to take input. Currently I can scan into the terminal, but then have to press enter to be able to do the next scan. I would like the be able to scan barcodes one after another without pressing enter.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkCxF.png)
Should auto enter here, so that it is ready to take new input

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qH2MP.png)

Comment: How does the barcode scanner input the characters to the command line? It seems weird that a computer (barcode scanner) talks to a computer (your python script) via an input command which is intended for human input. Could you not use some other mechanism? I really do not know how barcode scanners work to be fair

Comment: It plugs in via USB. As long as the python script is running and asking for user input I can just have my courser there and it will take the scan as if typed. Tho I want the input() to then auto enter when i am done scanning so i dont have to slow down.

Comment: I am open to using another input function. And there is an auto \t added by the scanner.

Comment: ah so it essentially acts like an usb keyboard. Interesting. And nice to know you figured it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my scanner is programmable and was able to change the \t at the end to a \n